# Unsure of how to compile this cpp project

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

I've been trying to get [this project](https://github.com/Mattli8312/Pacman2.0/tree/master) from github up and running, but I've encountered an issue with how the compiling works. I'm very inexperienced with compiling commands, so I looked around online and used pre-existing commands I've used on previous assignments where I've used SDL2. Except one issue I keep coming in to is that for some reason, it refuses to recognise files. Here's the command template I'm using on VSCODE on the .main file.

```
g++ /path/to/folder1/*.cpp /path/to/folder2/*.cpp /path/to/folder3/*.cpp -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o YourExecutableName
```

I keep getting errors where it's not recogising the files in those directories. Saying for example, no such file or directory for "include MazeGraph.h"

If anyone could help me figure this out I'd apprecaite it.

Comment: Looks like this command is not compiling from the directory where that github source code is. It's being executed from some other, mysterious directory, for some reason, due to all those `/path/to/whatever`s, for the cpp files. In that case, it looks like the shown command forgot the `-I` option that points to the same directories.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I made some changes with that in mind, which appear to be causing different and more complicated errors now. Here's my amended command:

g++ src/*.cpp Objects/*.cpp -Isrc -IObjects -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o YourExecutableName


There are still some leftovers error now, particularly that there are undefined references to "TTF_Init", "TTF_OpenFont" and RenderText Solid. I suspect this has to do with my SDL command:

/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:175: undefined reference to `SDL_main'

Comment: That means that it's not linking with the right libraries. Honestly, trying to build some random project off GitHub is not something that's realistically expected from someone's who "inexperienced". Typically, one needs to be an experienced, skilled developer who understands how compiling and linking works, and actually understands what each error message ***actually means***.